# Como buscar valor em Array/objeto em PHP?

Tags: php, array, objetos

Pessoal Tenho o seguinte array:

```
stdClass Object (
   [Chats] => Array (
       [0] => stdClass Object (
           [Chat] => stdClass Object (
               [ChatId] => 13383
               [UserId] => a2784a6dcf
               [SystemId] => a2784a6dcf~a2784a6dcf_OVL
               [Fullname] => chris
               [Email] => sadsad@gmail.com
           )
       )
       [1] => stdClass Object (
           [Chat] => stdClass Object (
               [ChatId] => 13383
               [UserId] => a2784a6dcf
               [SystemId] => a2784a6dcf~a2784a6dcf_OVL
               [Fullname] => chris
               [Email] => sadsad@gmail.com
           )
       )
   )
)
```

Estou na dúvida em como percorreria esses arrays pegando o valor `user_id`?

Como eu acesso o valor de `UserId`?

Comment: Já tentou fazer alguma coisa?

Comment: Já tentei assim: `$array->chats[0]->chat->UserId` mas não sei se está certo!

Comment: A ideia é essa, mas as chaves são `Chats` e `Chat`, com a letra `c` maiúscula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando que você possua a seguinte estrutura:

```
$data = (object) [
  "Chats" => [
    (object) ["Chat" => (object) ["ChatId" => 1000]],
    (object) ["Chat" => (object) ["ChatId" => 2000]],
    (object) ["Chat" => (object) ["ChatId" => 3000]],
    (object) ["Chat" => (object) ["ChatId" => 4000]],
    (object) ["Chat" => (object) ["ChatId" => 5000]],
  ]
];
```

> Vale notar que ao fazer o *cast* de um *array* associativo para `object` o PHP criará uma instância de `stdClass`, por isso podemos dizer que a estrutura acima é equivalente ao da pergunta apenas desconsiderando os campos não utilizados (`UserId`, `SystemId`, etc).

Você pode pegar a lista de ids de várias formas.

**1) Através de em laço de repetição**

```
$ChatIds = [];

foreach ($data->Chats as $Chat) {
    $ChatIds[] = $Chat->Chat->ChatId;
}
```

Obtendo o resultado `[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]`.

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/iWEBLG)</sup>

**2) Através da função `array_column`**

```
$Chats = array_column($data->Chats, "Chat");
$ChatIds = array_column($Chats, "ChatId");
```

Obtendo o resultado `[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]`.

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Ezjcvv)</sup>

**3) Através da função `array_map`**

```
$ChatIds = array_map(function ($chat) {
  return $chat->Chat->ChatId;
}, $data->Chats);
```

Obtendo o resultado `[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]`.

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/jtsuqO)</sup>

Comment: Perfeito! Utilizei a primeira forma que você disse, laço de repetição.
Eu nem conhecia essa array_map, vou pesquisar o funcionamento dela!

Answer (score 0):

Você terá que ir colocando as chaves como índices, execute o exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php
    $array[0]['teste'][12]['abc'] = "ola";
    print_r($array);
?>
```

Note que foi criado um array com a as chaves 0, teste, 12, abc que são os indices que levam até a informação "olá".

No seu exemplo provavelmente se foi atribuído a um array, o código poderá ficar desta forma:

```
$array["Chats"][0]["Chat"]["UserId"]
```

Comment: Se verificar a pergunta novamente verá que boa parte dos valores são, na verdade, objetos instâncias de `stdClass`, então o acesso se dá pela notação de objeto, não de *array*.

Comment: É verdade Anderson, não me atentei a isso e agora vi sua resposta lá em cima também e realmente tem coerência, é a falta dos caracteres "c" em letra maiúscula. Mas o bom é que se precisar manipular um array também já terá um exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Lá vai o que fiz:

Para acessar o valor de UserId, percebi que vou ter que utilizar a notação para acessar objetos (`->`) onde for `stdClass Object` e índices de array normal onde tiver `array`.

```
echo $array->Chats[0]->Chat->UserId;
```

Para percorrer esse array portanto, ficaria assim:

```
foreach ($array->Chats as $key => $array2){
    $aux .= $array2->Chat->UserId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo seu exemplo, bastaria fazer isso:

```
$obj = new stdClass('Chats');

$chat_obj_0 = new stdClass();
$chat_obj_0->ChatId = 133831;
$chat_obj_0->UserId = "a2784a6dcf1";
$chat_obj_0->SystemId = "a2784a6dcf~a2784a6dcf_OVL1";
$chat_obj_0->Fullname = "chris 1";
$chat_obj_0->Email = "sadsad1@gmail.com";

$chat_obj_1 = new stdClass();
$chat_obj_1->ChatId = 133832;
$chat_obj_1->UserId = "a2784a6dcf2";
$chat_obj_1->SystemId = "a2784a6dcf~a2784a6dcf_OVL2";
$chat_obj_1->Fullname = "chris 2";
$chat_obj_1->Email = "sadsad2@gmail.com";



   $n1 = (object) ['Chat' => $chat_obj_0];

   $n2 = (object) ['Chat' => $chat_obj_1];



$obj->Chats = array(
    0 =>  $n1,
    1 =>  $n2
  );


foreach($obj->Chats as $item) {

       echo 'Chat ID: ' . $item->Chat->ChatId . "<br>";
       echo 'User ID: ' . $item->Chat->UserId;
}

print_r($obj);
```

[**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/36YWG3)

Comment: Teu exemplo esta diferente do perguntando, se o objeto for como o da pergunta o correto seria `echo 'Chat ID: ' . $item->Chat->ChatId . "<br>";
       echo 'User ID: ' . $item->Chat->UserId;`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, não tinha visto, obrigado.